# pykakasi実行時KeyErrorの改善方法

Tags: python, python3, pykakasi

pythonでpykakasiを用いて日本語をローマ字に変換したいのですが、
実行しようとすると以下のエラーが出てしまいます。

```
KeyError: 'pykakasi\\hepburnhira2.pickle'
```

pykakasiはpipでインストールするとエラーになるという情報があったので、
pipを使わずgithubのリポジトリから直接インストールしています。

```
from pykakasi import kakasi
kakasi = kakasi()
kakasi.setMode('H', 'a')
kakasi.setMode('K', 'a')
kakasi.setMode('J', 'a')
conv = kakasi.getConverter()
result = conv.do("日本語")
print(result)
```

どなたか同じ問題を解決した方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか？

Comment: 念のため「githubから直接インストール」の手順も質問文に追記してもらうと、回答の参考になるかもしれません。「pipでインストールするとエラー」の件はFixされているようにも見えます。 - https://github.com/miurahr/pykakasi/issues/17

Comment: Windowsを使っていますか？pipでインストールするか、直接インストールする場合は chcp 65001 しないと文字化けします。

Comment: Windowsを使っています。chcp65001とはどのような作業でしょうか？諸学者のため知識が無く恐縮です

Comment: chcp 65001 はコマンドプロンプトの文字コードをutf-8に変更するコマンドです。調べたらプログラムの方でutf-8の指定ができているので今回は関係ないようです。pykakasiをもう一度インストールし直してそのログを保管しておいて、もし今回のバグが再現するようであれば、そのログを追加で貼ってください。

Answer (score 1):

`pykakasi`のGitHubのIssuをみると`KeyError: 'pykakasi\hepburnhira2.pickle'`というエラーが発生するバグが過去にあリましたが既にFixされています。また、`pykakasi`の最新のバージョン0.93をインストールしてみましたが、問題は発生しません。

念のため現在インストールされている`pykakasi`をアンインストールしてから、

```
pip uninstall pykakasi
```

どの方法でインストールしても正常に動作すると思います。

```
//PyPIから
pip install pykakasi
//GitHubのリポジトリから
pip install git+https://github.com/miurahr/pykakasi
//GitHubのreleaseから
pip install https://github.com/miurahr/pykakasi/archive/v0.93.zip
```